# replace comma within brackets

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have the below text and I am trying to replace the commas inside the brackets alone.

[alpha ,beta, theta01, zeta01], [x9001, A2201, zeta01]
The intended output is

[alpha beta theta01 zeta01], [x9001 A2201 zeta01]
I am trying to accomplish this using the regular expression

```
WITH t AS (SELECT '[alpha, beta,theta01,zeta01], [x9001, A2201, zeta01]' col1 
             )
SELECT t.col1
     ,REGEXP_REPLACE(t.col1, "(\\[[A-Za-z0-9]*)*,", "\\1") new_col
  FROM t;
```

\[ -- escaped character [
\1 -- escaped group pattern

however, the comma between the brackets is also getting removed. here is the output I am getting

[alpha beta theta01 zeta01]  [x9001 A2201 zeta01]
**<----<>**

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select col1,
  ( select string_agg(regexp_replace(el, ',', ''), ', ')
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(col1, r'\[.*?\]')) el
  ) new_col
from t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you! consider also voting up the answer :o)